# Truncating or Summarizing Text with html part in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Am loading some blog data from a database with title and body but the body contains some `HTML` and `CSS` codes like the following below in the `JSON` data

```
{[News_Body: "<span style=\"color: black;\">The Lagos State Local Government 
            Election Appeal Tribunal have received 22 Appeals from the July 
            22 council polls in Lagos State.<br />\n <br />\n The 
            Chairperson of the 2017 Local Government Election Appeal 
            Tribunal, Justice G. M Onyeabo, stated this today 25th of 
            October at the tribunal's inaugural sitting. &nbsp;<br />\n <br 
            />\n The tribunal had earlier been inaugurated on the 23 of 
            October, 2017 pursuant to Section 7 of the Local Government 
            Election Tribunal Law 2008, will hear and determine the appeals 
            in 21 days.<br />\n <br />\n Justice Onyeabo and four other 
            justices: O. Kasali, A. Onigbanjo, O.A Dabiri and K. A Jose make 
            up the panel.<br />\n <br />"
News_Title: "PRESS RELEASE - LAGOS LG ELECTION APPEAL TRIBUNAL RECEIVES 22 
            APPEALS"
Posted_By: "Ololade Ige"
Posted_Date: "10/31/2017 12:00:00 AM"], ...}
```

The problem I have is taking the body and summarizing its contents. I tried the following but it did not work as expected.

using CSS

```
.truncate {
  height: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Loading the data dynamically with javascript because it is coming from database

```
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.setAttribute('style', 'text-align:center; color: #ffffff !important;');
p.setAttribute('class', 'truncate');
var newSum = summary.split('<br />');;
p.innerHTML = newSum[0];
```

but the problem with the above is that not all `object.News_Body` contains a line break `<br />`. I don't have control as to how the data is stored, I just process what am given. Sadly :(

Comment: You could strip the html from the data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript The stipped data can then be desplayed like you want to!

Comment: on your `.truncate` CSS class, it seems odd that you have a height defined as 200px but then you set `nowrap`. I would think you would still want your text to wrap

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery is an option you could achieve something very quickly using the text function and some string manipulation.

```
var text = $("<div>" + content.News_Body + "</div>").text().substring(0, 3) + "..."
```

Just replace the 3 with your max content length. So `substring(0, 10)` will show 10 characters etc...

EDIT:

Using the link that @FMK posted at [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript) it would look like:

```
var text = strip("<div>" + content.News_Body + "</div>").substring(0, 3) + "..."
```

Which is a non-jquery option too.

Comment: It worked but spat an error --->  **Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Three judges of the Lagos High Court have been elevated to the Court of .<br />**
 <br />

Comment: I assume not all of your content is exact HTML tags then. Surrounding the code in a div should work. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I combined the two replies and I did this.

```
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.setAttribute('style', 'text-align:center; color: #ffffff !important;');
    p.setAttribute('class', '');// removed my css truncate style class

    var s = strip(summary).substring(0, 300) + "...";

    p.innerHTML = s;
```

I got the strip function from [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Thanks for the quick replies. You guys are awsome!!